# Using maven android archetype with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to use the following archetype.
https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki/Android-release-archetype

I can follow the instructions on the page fine (using the terminal)
I was wondering, how do I do this in Eclipse? Is there a sort of command line interface I can input the required commands?
  i.e

```
   mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-release \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.5 \
  -DgroupId=com.foo.bar \
  -DartifactId=my-android-project \
  -Dpackage=com.foo.bar.android
```

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Install [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin
2. create new maven project
3. next button takes you to archetype selection
4. optionally configure archetype catalogues, shouldn't be necessary for this archetype (android-release), as the latest version 1.0.5 is in the central maven repo.
5. next, next, next ...

Update:

To get it working I did the following:

1. download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml save it as user-home/.m2/central-archetype-catalog.xml
2. in eclipse create new maven project
3. next button
4. configure catalogs, add new local catalog point to file created in step 1.
5. after closing the catalog configuration dialog, make sure that the drop-down catalog selector is on all catalogs or on the new local catalog that you just defined
6. in the filter type 'android-release'
7. select the android-release archetype and click next
8. enter your selected group-id and artifact-id

I did notice a problem reported that the project directory could not be renamed.
The project had been created on disk, so I imported it into eclipse using
Import > Maven > Existing maven projects

Comment: thank you
I did what you said, it sorta worked, but this only uses the android-quickstart-archetype.
But I want to use the Android-Release Archetype instead.
I do now know how to do this in Eclipse. I have tried to add a catalog, but I don't know what I am doing.
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting with a new project you can use the Maven Android archetypes to create Android projects completely within Eclipse you just need to do the following:

1. Create a new Maven Project (*File* -> *New* -> *Project...* then select
   *Maven* -> *Maven Project*).
2. When prompted to *Select Archetype* click Add Archetype...
3. In the dialog that appears enter "de.akquinet.android.archetypes" for *Archetype Group Id*.
4. In *Archetype Artifact Id* enter "android-quickstart".
5. In *Archetype Version* enter "1.0.6" and continue.
6. When prompted enter your desired project group and artifact ID, version and, optionally, set the "platform" property for the Android version (defaults to '7').
7. Set the "android-plugin-version" property for the Android version to '3.0.0'.
8. Click Finish
9. Right-click on new project and select Maven -> Update Project Configuration.