# Failure with Maven Android : The POM for com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:13.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, android, maven

This is the error that I am getting with my current Maven Android Project.

```
The POM for com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:13.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I have tried reinstalling google play services from SDK Manager and running mnv clean install still it does not work.

Any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue localized to your system

Comment: @Kevin this is completely valid question to me atleast

Comment: Without access to the OP's machine, it's almost impossible to fix these errors as they are specific to their configuration. Also, google returns this generic response : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416295/dependencies-dependency-version-for-com-google-androidandroidjar-is-missing

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155609/missing-artifactcom-google-android-gmsgoogle-play-servicesjar-in-pom-xml

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure maven can access the repository the artifact can be found in. For example maven central http://search.maven.org/ does not contain the that artifact.

I would expect a settings.xml or a pom.xml to contain some  section in that define where to look for this.

if you can execute maven commands try: `mvn help:effective-settings` 
and as well: `mvn help:effective-pom`
that should reveal some repositories.

Another issue may be that you need to configure a proxy server for maven if you are behind one.

Is the message a warning or an error? Because it is also common that some artifacts do not have a pom.xml. So if it is a warning but everything else works just ignore it :)