# Missing artifactcom.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar in pom.xml

Tags: android, google-maps, maven

I am getting below error in dependencies tag in my pom.xml file.

```
Missing artifact com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:13.0.0
Missing artifact com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:apklib:13.0.0
```

Here is my Pom.xml dependencies tag, where I am getting error(Check `ERROR HERE` line)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>maps</artifactId>
        <version>17_r3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> //ERROR HERE
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you configured the correct maven repository to get `google-play-services`?

Comment: I am using maven android sdk deployer to find the jar but inside my repository C:\Users\amrit\.m2\repository\com\google\android\gms\google-play-services\13.0.0 it's not showing any jar instead there are 3 LASTUPDATED files

Comment: https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer, which I am using to get the required files

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the path com.google.android.gms does not exist in the central Maven repository.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I was able to resolve this by downloading the `Google Repository` extras package found in the Android SDK Manager. (**NOTE** I am using Android Studio which I believe automatically picks up this repository otherwise you may have to copy some files into your local m2 repo or configure your pom/build file accordingly :S)

It looks to install all versions of the library using an understandable semantic version (instead of their regular `r13`/'13.0.0` style) so you will have to set your version number accordingly (currently at version 4.2.42 at time of writing)

It would be nice if Google provided (and documented) a public repository for these artifacts, or even better had them published on maven central (as Dallas187 stated) but I'm sure there is probably some legal tarpit that they have to cross before this can happen...